# Regex for getting the date

Tags: regex, oracle

The query

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Outstanding Trade Ticket Report_08 Apr 14.xlsx', '\_(.*)\.') AS FILE_DATE FROM DUAL
```

gives the OUTPUT:

```
_08 Apr 14.
```

Please advise the correct regex to be used for getting the date without the characters.
I can use RTRIM and LTRIM but want to try it using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Outstanding Trade Ticket Report_08 Apr 14.xlsx', '\_(.*)\.', 
1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual
```

The last argument is used to determine which matched group to return.

Link to [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27613)

Comment: Thanks Alfasin. Can you please shed some light on how exactly do the parameters work in the syntax? `REGEXP_SUBSTR(source_string, pattern
[, position [, occurrence
[, match_parameter]]])` I'm very bad at regex :|